# Listfragment divided into sections

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am programming for android 4.0

I would like to create a listFragment divided in 2 sections. This means i want it to be 1 long scrollable list but with a divider between the online items and the offline items. And of course when one item comes online it should jump upwards + the other way around.

All the items are clickable but the divider shouldn't be (and preferably have a differend colour)

How can i do this or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so , a fragment is basically an activity and you can treat it like an activity, in your case you should extend [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) (which will act like a `ListActivity` in a sense).

now, a List Adapter (which populate a list) in its default way will only allow you to display a list in its most simple form so in order to achieve what you want (a list that deals certain list items differently) you will need to write your own Adapter.
its best if you get the data in the order you want them to be displayed so if you can sort the "online" items from the "offline" items straight from your data source you should query it this way. so now the only thing you need to add is a separator between them and you can do it by finding the first "offline" item and inflating a separator above it (this is done inside your adapter).

each task by its own has dozens of tutorials and Q&As around the web and on StackOverflow.
hope it helps and i'm here if you need more help.